# How can I merge a column from data frame to another column from the same data frame?

Tags: r, multiple-columns

So, I'd like to merge one columns in another column at the bottom. That's how my data looks like:

```
    V1      V2       V3       V4
-75.6364 -33.3363 -68.6320 -35.7657 
-62.4546 -42.6754 -60.0532 -41.7773   
-53.1363 -48.3385 -56.0956 -47.4524 
-51.9633 -37.6143 -60.3062 -54.7817
```

And I'd like to have this, merge V1-V3 and V2-V4:

```
    V1      V2       

-75.6364 -33.3363 
-62.4546 -42.6754    
-53.1363 -48.3385  
-51.9633 -37.6143 
-68.6320 -35.7657 
-60.0532 -41.7773  
-56.0956 -47.4524
```

I was looking for at this page but I just found `cbind` and `rbind` options 
but do not offer me what I want.

Comment: take a look at `join` in the `dplyr` package or `merge` from base R.

Comment: It looks like you want to stack columns V1 and V2 on top of columns V3 and V4. Is that right?

Comment: I think the desired output is missing the 8th row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers are helpful, but in each you will have to literally code in each pair of columns. Here is a generalized function with a tougher example with ten columns below:

```
dfSeq <- function(df) Map(':', 1:(ncol(df)-1), 2:ncol(df))[c(TRUE,FALSE)]
stackDF <- function(df1) do.call('rbind', Map(function(x,y)
                setNames(x[y], names(df1)[1:2]), list(df1), dfSeq(df1)))


mydf <- as.data.frame(replicate(10, rnorm(10)))
dim(mydf)
[1] 10 10

stackDF(mydf)
#              V1          V2
# 1   1.031131668 -1.00884258
# 2   1.803293498  2.15713217
# 3  -1.295998573  0.20951434
# 4  -1.314269143  1.56329500
# 5  -1.138388270 -0.87029891
# 6  -1.312514370  0.31815244
# 7   1.436570621 -0.96508931
```

**Edit**

Using Ananda's technique [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29213822/convert-data-frame-of-n-columns-into-a-data-frame-of-two-stacked-columns), we can create a one-liner:

```
data.frame(V1=unlist(mydf[c(T,F)]), V2=unlist(mydf[c(F,T)]))
```

Answer (score 3):

data.table's `melt` function is particularly nice in that it can take parameters to group into parallel columns. It will insert a `variable` identifier column, but you can subset that out.

```
library(data.table)

melt(setDT(df),                              # set df to a data.table
     measure.vars = list(c(1,3), c(2,4)),    # set column groupings
     value.name = 'V')[                      # set output name scheme
      , -1, with = F]                        # subset out variable column
##          V1       V2
## 1: -75.6364 -33.3363
## 2: -62.4546 -42.6754
## 3: -53.1363 -48.3385
## 4: -51.9633 -37.6143
## 5: -68.6320 -35.7657
## 6: -60.0532 -41.7773
## 7: -56.0956 -47.4524
## 8: -60.3062 -54.7817
```

---

In base R, the `stack` function melts to long, but not for parallel columns. However, you can turn the column names into indices to use to `unstack`, or just make a suitable vector by hand with something like `rep(rep(1:2, each = 4), 2)`.

```
df2 <- stack(df)
# change ind (variable/key/index) column to number, take modulo 2 to separate even/odd,
# and invert 0/1 add 1 to make better column names
df2$ind <- 1 + !as.numeric(df2$ind) %% 2
unstack(df2)
##         X1       X2
## 1 -75.6364 -33.3363
## 2 -62.4546 -42.6754
## 3 -53.1363 -48.3385
## 4 -51.9633 -37.6143
## 5 -68.6320 -35.7657
## 6 -60.0532 -41.7773
## 7 -56.0956 -47.4524
## 8 -60.3062 -54.7817
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to stack each pair of columns. In the code below, we just change the names of columns 3 and 4 to be the same as columns 1 and 2, so that `rbind` will work as desired:

```
new.df = rbind(df[,1:2], setNames(df[,3:4], names(df[,1:2])))

new.df
```

> ```
>         V1       V2
> 1 -75.6364 -33.3363
> 2 -62.4546 -42.6754
> 3 -53.1363 -48.3385
> 4 -51.9633 -37.6143
> 5 -68.6320 -35.7657
> 6 -60.0532 -41.7773
> 7 -56.0956 -47.4524
> 8 -60.3062 -54.7817
> ```